# GString performance

Tags: string, groovy, double-quotes, single-quotes, gstring

If I need plain string in Groovy, does using double-quoted literals make any influence on performance?

For instance:

```
def plainString = 'Custom string'
def gString = "Custom string"
```

In my understanding, plain `String` should be faster because during runtime there are no searches for specific characters and substitutions.

Comment: Why are you worrying about it?
If you're experiencing performance problems, you should be profiling. If you're profiling, you already know the answer.
If you're not experiencing performance problems, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Groovy Language Specification](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string):

> Double quoted strings are plain `java.lang.String` if there’s no interpolated expression, but are `groovy.lang.GString` instances if interpolation is present.

Therefore, feel free to use double quotes or single quotes: they will result in the same type of object. The difference will be when you have a `$` in the double-quoted string. But by then, we are talking semantics, not performance.